# Is it necessary to optimize this query with multiple left joins and inner joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I'm using Mariadb 10. I have built a query to fetch variants of models. It is quite straight forward.
Here's an example (More columns to fetch in my real case):

```
$sql = "
SELECT v.name,v.color,v.material,
       m.modelID,m.model_overview,
       b.brand,b.brand_overview,
       s.seller,s.sell_id,s.price,
       rm.similar_model,rm.similar_model_overview,
       r.review,r.rating
FROM variant v 
  INNER JOIN model m ON v.modelID = m.modelID
  INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandID = m.brandID
  LEFT JOIN seller s ON s.sellerID = v.sellerID 
  LEFT JOIN related_model rm ON rm.modelID = m.modelID
  LEFT JOIN review r ON r.modelID = m.modelID
  // more left joins to other tables ON m.modelID in real case 
WHERE v.ID = :id";

$dbh->prepare($sql);
```

I vaguely remember from an article that in order to avoid create large sets of rows as a result of multiple left joins, it may be a good idea to group the inner join queries in a subquery, and then use the returned modelID to left-join the other tables, like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT all.*,s.seller,s.sell_id,s.price,
       rm.similar_model,rm.similar_model_overview,
       r.review,r.rating
FROM (
  SELECT v.name,v.color,v.material,
       m.modelID,m.model_overview,
       b.brand,b.brand_overview,
       v.sellerID
  FROM variant v 
       INNER JOIN model m ON v.modelID = m.modelID
       INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandID = m.brandID
       WHERE v.ID = :id
)all 
LEFT JOIN seller s ON s.sellerID = all.sellerID 
LEFT JOIN related_model rm ON rm.modelID = all.modelID
LEFT JOIN review r ON r.modelID = all.modelID";
```

Is it true? Is this query better than the original one performance-wise?

Comment: What has your testing shown you?

Comment: The redis suggestion seems useless, since you get only the rows with the lowest v.ID values.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- this should help answer the question and provide more insight into what is going on.

Comment: Extremely unlikely - but easy to test

Comment: Thank you all. I'll make a test in a while.